# Replace qualifying spaces with &nbsp;

Tags: php, regex, replace, spaces

I want to replace all the spaces with `&nbsp;` which are only followed by `Fig. space digit/s and dot`.

For example if the string is:

```
Fig. 1. sasasa 
Fig. 34. 345 dffdfd etc. dsds
```

I want to change it to:

```
Fig.&nbsp;1.&nbsp; sasasa 
Fig.&nbsp;34.&nbsp; 345 dffdfd etc. dsds
```

Is there a way to do it with regex? I have tried the regex `/(Fig\.\s)(\d+)(\\.)(\s+)/` but it matches `Fig.` followed by space followed by digit/s followed by dot and space but I only want those spaces which are preceded by the pattern.

PS: The reason I want to do this is because I am trying to split sentences ending with dot and space. But in some sentences there are some words and numerics followed by dot and space (such as `Fig. 1.` or `Mr. etc`), so I want to replace those dots and spaces to `&nbsp;` so that the sentences are split correctly.

Comment: Could you please provide one more example? And post the relevant code you are using.

Comment: Why no match `345<here>dffdfd` ? Otherwise, it's simply _Find_ `(?:(?!\A)\G|(Fig))([\d.]*)[ ]`, _Replace_ `$1$2&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky regex to do right.

This will match your subject string as you matched it.

Globally find: `(?:(?!\A)\G|(Fig))([\d.]*)(?<=[ .])[ ]`
Replace: `$1$2&nbsp;`

https://regex101.com/r/91hgVD/3

Comments

```
 (?:
      (?! \A )              # Not Begin of String
      \G                    # \G anchor, start where last left off
   |                      # or
                            # Reset's \G
      ( Fig )               # (1), Fig
 )
 ( [\d.]* )            # (2), Optional digits or dots
 (?<= [ .] )           # Must be a dot or space behind
 [ ]                   # space
```

Note - there is a little *magic* going on between   `([\d.]*)` and `(?<=[ .])`

The optional [\d.] will consume digits and dots,
but the (?<=[ .])  will require a dot before the space *OR* another space.
But will not match `Fig <space>` for instance.

Comment: This one also worked. For simplicity reason I accepted the above answer, but I really appreciate your answer for the explanations. I have upvoted but is will be shown only after I get 15 plus rep score. Thank you Sln.

Comment: This worked perfectly for all cases not just Fig. but also Mr.  St. and what ever words I don't want to be followed by dot I used your regex repeated times for each of the word(ex Fig. Mr. St. etc). This regex solved my problem perfectly! I am accepting this answer now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KrishnaBasada - Yeah, you could combine them into an alternation. Instead of just `Fig` you could add as many as you want `(?:Fig|St|Ms|Mrs|Mr)` etc..

Comment: Thanks again for reply sln. I have added one more condition [A-Z] to escape the names with capital initials as S.M. Jones which replaces to S.M.&nbsp;Jones. I used this regex: preg_replace('/(?:(?!\A)\G|(Fig|Mr|Mrs|St|etc|[A-Z]))([\d.]*)(?<=[ .])[ ]/', '$1$2&nbsp;', $str);

Answer (score 0):

Try the Regex and `preg_replace_callback()` function from this example:

```
$str ='Fig. 1. sasasa Fig. 34. 345 dffdfd etc. dsds';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(Fig\.)[ ]([0-9]+[\.]{1})[ ]*/i', function($m){
  return str_ireplace(' ', '&nbsp;', $m[0]);
}, $str);

echo $str;  // Fig.&nbsp;1.&nbsp;sasasa Fig.&nbsp;34.&nbsp;345 dffdfd etc. dsds
```

Or, from this:

```
$str ='Fig. 1. sasasa Fig. 34. 345 dffdfd etc. dsds';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(Fig\.)[ ]([0-9]+[\.]{1})[ ]*/i', function($m){
  return str_ireplace([$m[1].' ', $m[2]], [$m[1].'&nbsp;', $m[2].'&nbsp;'], $m[0]);
}, $str);

echo $str; // Fig.&nbsp;1.&nbsp; sasasa Fig.&nbsp;34.&nbsp; 345 dffdfd etc. dsds
```

Comment: Excellent! Can't believe I got the answer so quick!. Thanks a bunch CoursesWeb. I am not so good at using regex, but I am so happy you helped me and you saved my day. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you have yourself a doozie of an XY Problem.  Your *actual* challenge is to split sentences properly, but instead, you are mutating substrings to try to differentiate dots from full stops.

While I would rather put my effort into solving the original problem, I find the other answers to be over-engineered, so I'll recommend a lighter pattern.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gcUn5))

```
$string = <<<STRING
Fig. 1. sasasa 
Fig. 34. 345 dffdfd etc. dsds
STRING;

echo preg_replace('~Fig\.\K (\d+\.) ~', '&nbsp;$1&nbsp;', $string);
```

Output:

```
Fig.&nbsp;1.&nbsp;sasasa 
Fig.&nbsp;34.&nbsp;345 dffdfd etc. dsds
```

`\K` matches, then forgets `Fig.`. Then the next space is matched. Then the number and dot are captured. Then the next space is matched.  The replacement uses the captured substring and wraps it in htmlencoded spaces.

My snippet intentionally replaces the space after the "number and dot", so that you don't have redundant spacing in your text.